# AngularJS UI Router -> Could not resolve when using ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angular-ui-router

I have setup a JSON file with my ui-routes in and that works.

But I having trouble using the Link. I have manged to use it when it comes to using the following state:

```
{
    "name": "home",
    "url": "^/home",
    "abstract": false,
    "parent": "root",
    "views": [{
        "name": "container@",
        "templateUrl": "/pages/home/index.html",
        "controller": "HomeCtrl"
    }]
},
```

To access this I use:

```
<a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
```

And this works perfectly.

But the problem comes when I try and do a 'ui-sref' with parameters. So for example if was to and get to this state:

```
{
    "name": "approach:module:section",
    "url": "^/approach/:module/:section",
    "controller": "ApproachCtrl",
    "abstract": true,
    "parent": "root",
    "views": [{
        "name": "container@",
        "templateUrl": "/pages/approach/overview.html"
    }]
}
```

From reading the documentation and other online tutorials I thought the code should now be:

```
<a ui-sref="approach({module: 'overview', section: '1'})">Approach</a>
```

This doesn't seem to work. I seem to get the following issue:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'root.approach' from state 'home'
```

Where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks,
Kane

Comment: I think its because you have a parent property in your second route, try removing it

Comment: Thanks for that but doesn't seem to work either. Both of the objects have a parent property so not sure if thats what you mean.
This is what I did:

  ` {
       "name": "approach:module:section",
       "url": "^/approach/:module/:section",
       "controller": "ApproachCtrl",
       "abstract": true,
       "views": [{
           "name": "container@",
           "templateUrl": "/pages/approach/overview.html"
       }]
   }`

Comment: You can see the my JSON of pages here:
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nz0maZOEjVZJrsxD2cbF?p=catalogue)

It also shows with ui-sref works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but i think that ui-router is trying to find **root.approach** but it could not find it maybe as you have named your state as **approach:module:section**. Try renaming your state to **approach**

Comment: Yeah it works when I create a state **approach** but I want to use the parameters of **:module & :section** which is what I thought  _name: approach:module:section_ allowed me to do.

Comment: Yea you can use the parameters of **:module and :section** through the url but not in the state name as you have declared in your state `"url": "^/approach/:module/:section" ` is how you are passing parameters to your state and alternate method would be `"url": "^/approach/{module}/{section}"` 
Is your problem solved btw?

Comment: I have just changed the name to `approach` and url to `^/approach/{module}/{section}` and it now works. From the way I read it I thought the state needed to know that parameters would be sent in state name.

Comment: great! can you mark my answer as the correct answer?  :)